# SQL - Join two tables based on a condition

Tags: sql, duplicates, conditional-statements, left-join, case

I have an issue.

Table 1 ->
It has columns ID1 and Date1 (yyyymmdd) and Time1 (hh:mm:ss)

Table 2 ->
It has columns ID2 and Date2  (yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss)

None of the ID columns are unique.
What my first intention was, joining the tables on ID1=ID2 and date1 = cast (date2 as date)
and time1= cast(date2 as time).
However, I realized that time of Time1 and Date2 are not the same although they supposed to be.

Instead, I wanted to see what happens if I only joined using ID and date, excluding time.
With left join, I have only one extra row. That is because : I have more than one row in table 2
with the corresponding ID1 and Date1 values. Therefore join returns 2 rows instead of 1 row. BUT one of the time values in table1 and table2 actually match up.

To sum up :
I can't have the correct results when I join the tables by using ID,date, and time columns in table1.
I have one extra row when I join the tables by using only ID and date.

Is there any way that I can set up a condition -somewhere in the query-so that the query does the join by ID and date columns as a default but when this row duplication is a possibility, it will include time column, too?
I mean, I actually want to mix up "join on" and "case when".
I hope I could tell the problem understandable enough. Thank you all !

Comment: you could get the count of records matching the join by date and if that is > 1 then use the time to select which one you want.  You didn't tag the database you are using - in Sql Server this could be built into an outer apply that only returns at most one matching record from the second table.

Comment: Hey Scott 
Thank you for your response.
It is MSSQL Server, sorry to miss that.
Since IDs are not unique , I have records like:
Table 1 has an ID number with let's say 5 different dates: 1st of jan,feb,mar,apr and may. Table 2 has IDs on those days. So that is 5 matches. 
I have a lot of IDs like this. ( Having matches more than 1 ) So >1 does not work for me. I don't know how I can handle it.

Comment: You are going to have to provide some sample data explaining what you are trying to do so it can be understood better.  Also include the sql you have tried and show why it is not working as desired.  It might be best to review this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  The better you describe your question the better chance of getting help without a lot of back and forth in comments.